# How is access restricted in the ASP.NET Core web app template when using ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core 5 web app that's using ASP.NET Core Identity for authorization. I have scaffolded all of the Identity UI so that I can see how it works.

Within the scaffolded Razor pages in the "Identity" area, I can see several page model classes that are decorated with `[AllowAnonymous]`, but I can't see any reference to anything that *restricts* access.

There must be something somewhere, though, because some pages in the template website are accessible when not signed in (even though they do not have `[AllowAnonymous]`), yet most pages in the scaffolded `Identity` area are *not* accessible unless signed-in.

How is this achieved? I expected to see a call to `AuthorizeFolder` (or `AuthorizeAreaFolder`) but I can't see one anywhere in the project.

I'd like to add some authorization rules of my own, but I'd like to know what the *existing* rules are before I start making changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain full control of the Identity UI, run the Identity scaffolder and select Override all files.

You might want to do this to have full control of the Identity UI.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
        // services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Identity", "/Account/Manage");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaPage("Identity", "/Account/Logout");
        });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = $"/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = $"/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = $"/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    });

    // using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
    services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
}
```

Reference: [Create full Identity UI source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source)

[Simple authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Razor Pages authorization conventions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks. I *had* run the scaffolder and generated all the files (see my first paragraph). However I had missed the steps in your first link, so I do still have a call to `AddDefaultIdentity`. That *must* be what's setting the authorization policy... and yet, when I look at the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityServiceCollectionUIExtensions.cs) for that method, I see nothing that sets any authorization rules (and indeed nothing specific to the scaffolded Identity UI). So, my question still stands - where are these rules being applied?

Comment: Ah, found it. It's in the class [`IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8b30d862de6c9146f466061d51aa3f1414ee2337/src/Identity/UI/src/IdentityDefaultUIConfigureOptions.cs) which is indirectly referenced by `AddDefaultIdentity`.